# make sure the records should be unique base on SEQ number?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
Name,Age,Seq

G,30,1
G,31,1
K,28,3
K,29,3
k,28,3
V,,4
V,28,4
```

make sure the records should be unique base on SEQ number. 
    If seq is repeating you have to update the existing record with latest value.

I'm begineer in sql how can i achieve above problem statement?

Comment: Please try once with learning sql....If there'll still  be any problem,ask the problem.....

Comment: what should be the result look like?

Comment: Look into an `UPDATE` using: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Name,Age)`.  Then add an unique index on Name+Seq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the table is called t_values then you can get the records that do not have distinct SEQ numbers as follows:-

```
SELECT        V.Name,V.Age,V.Seq
FROM          t_values AS V
INNER JOIN    (
    SELECT        Seq, count(Seq) AS total
    FROM          t_values
    GROUP BY      Seq
    HAVING        count(Seq) > 1
) AS D
    ON        V.Seq = D.Seq
```

What happens here is the inner select gets all the Seq values that have a duplicate value. Then we do an inner join back on the same table to get the ones that have equivalent Seq values.

Will this fit the bill for you?